# Is it possible to ignore the CLASSPATH variable in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

Our IT department has set up a JRE on our machines we can't remove, and they also set the global CLASSPATH variable to point to that.

Is there a way to configure Maven to ignore it? It's blocking my ability to run `javadoc` from Maven and the only remedy on SO is to remove that variable. I can do it manually, but would like to know if I can have Maven just ignore it or unset it.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by this.  I didn't think that Maven paid any attention whatsoever to the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Apparently the javadoc plugin is impacted by it. I'm guessing it happens when it executes the process. It must be picking up the variable then.

Comment: I think it is more likely that `javadoc` hasn't been passed the appropriate command line arguments by Maven.  The javadoc plugin is supposed to build a `-classpath` argument from the project and its compile scoped dependencies.

Comment: First if such IT department make such a setup it is doing wrong. JRE does not make sense anymore ... furthermore setting a CLASSPATH veriable shows much more that it is wrong. It might be doing like setting JAVA_HOME... apart from that you can override your user environment with other values... if you can call javadoc than you are using not an JDK so you are using an JRE instead which means you should set your JAVA_HOME instead correctly.